# Merge objects in an array if they have the same date

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects. If 2 or more objects share the same date, I want to merge them together as one object. For example, if I have this:

```
const rawData = [
  {
    date: '3/10/2019',
    a: '123',
  },
  {
    date: '3/10/2019',
    b: '456',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    a: '789',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    b: '012',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    c: '345',
  }
];
```

Then I want the modified array to look like this:

```
const myDesiredResult = [
  {
    date: '3/10/2019',
    a: '123',
    b: '456',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    a: '789',
    b: '012',
    c: '345',
  }
];
```

The original objects will always have 2 items, date and something else, but there is no limit to what might be paired with the date. Could range from a - c, a-z, etc.

I'd prefer to do this with plain javascript as long as there is a clean way to do it, but I'm open to using lodash if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for reduce.

```js
const rawData = [
  {
    date: '3/10/2019',
    a: '123',
  },
  {
    date: '3/10/2019',
    b: '456',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    a: '789',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    b: '012',
  },
  {
    date: '3/11/2019',
    c: '345',
  }
];

const groupByDate = array => array.reduce((results, item) => {
  const current = results.find(i => i.date === item.date);
  if (current) {
    for (let property in item) {
      if (property !== 'date') {
        current[property] = item[property];
      }
    }
  } else {
    results.push({...item});
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(groupByDate(rawData));
```