# JSON: put object into an array when they have the same date and keep the array with the date in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, filter

so i have

```
  const att = [
    {
      date: '2022-11-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-11-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'absent' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-11-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-11-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-12-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-12-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'sick' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-12-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-12-04',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-04-14',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-04-14',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-04-14',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-04-14',
      attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }],
    },
  ];
```

and i want to turn it into

```
  const final = [
    {
      date: '2022-11-04',
      attendance: [
        { playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'absent' },
        { playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' },
      ],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-12-04',
      attendance: [
        { playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'sick' },
        { playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' },
      ],
    },
    {
      date: '2022-04-14',
      attendance: [
        { playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' },
        { playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

so i want to push the object in an array when they have the same date and end up with the date and all their attendance for that date

i tried: [Merge objects in an array if they have the same date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130407/merge-objects-in-an-array-if-they-have-the-same-date)  but that wasnt with an array with the object and when they have the same name (i have attendance for every object and the example had different names)

i set up a workplace here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vu27ry

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) _StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the date and the `value` is the attendance array. In the end, the map values will be the list of grouped objects

```js
const arr = [
  {
    date: '2022-11-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-11-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'absent' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-11-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-11-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-12-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-12-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'sick' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-12-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-12-04',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-04-14',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Play Last', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-04-14',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'New Player Jona', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-04-14',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jona Hysi', status: 'present' }]
  },
  {
    date: '2022-04-14',
    attendance: [{ playerName: 'Jurgen Tafaj', status: 'present' }]
  }
];

const res = [...
  arr.reduce((map, { date, attendance = [] }) => {
    const { attendance: dateAttendance = [] } = map.get(date) ?? {};
    map.set(date, { date, attendance: [...dateAttendance, ...attendance] });
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: your amazing thanks. also do you have a video recommendation when they explain these function like .reduce, .set, .filter etc. because im new at this and im finding difficult to modify arrays and object the way i want. again really really thank you<3!

Comment: @JurgenTafaj, you're welcome. The official docs are good.

Comment: ok i will try thanks for everything